# How to load Dyanamic values to dropdown list in MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Here i am trying to create dynamic dropdown list which load items from the Viewmodel of View,

here is my model
[image]
I have created view model as below
[image]

passing View model to MVC View

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        OrgVM model = new OrgVM();
        model.regions = getRegions();
        return View(model);
    }
          private List<Region> getRegions()
           {
            var list = new List<Region>();
                list = context.Set<Region>().ToList().Select(s => new Region
                {
                    Id = s.RegionId,
                    Name = s.Name,
                }).ToList();            
            return list;
        }
```

now here in Create View am calling View model as below,

```
@model xyz.ViewModels.OrgVM
```

and am generating dropdown like

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.regions, new SelectList(Model.regions), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and it looks like below snapp, where it has to show dyanamic values in that dropdown list.
[image]

Comment: try this in csHTML " new SelectList(Model.regions, "Name", "Description" )

Comment: @MithunPattankar it's not working,

Comment: I would suggest using "The Select Tag Helper"; preferred way in ASP.NET Core

Comment: Its `new SelectList(Model.regions, "RegionId", "Name" )`

Comment: But you using a view model, so the property should be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> regions { get; set; }` (you use a view model to pass the correct data to the view in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this with little R and D

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.regions,Model.regions.Select(d => new 
           SelectListItem()
             {
                 Value = d.RegionId.ToString(),
                 Text = d.Name.ToString()
             }))
```